# Any suggestions on how start development of mobile site in adobe cq 5.4

Tags: adobe, aem, crx, day-cq

can anybody provide any pointers on where to start the development of mobile site in day cq?
Also please share if there are any websites for tutorials?
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This question is far too vague.

Comment: I have some experience in cq website development, but not sure how to convert the site to mobile site... was thinking if there are any sort of simulators available where templates can be tested on...

Comment: Mobile site development for the existing website using live copy and multi site manager.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsEZSfdL9JI 
I know 'm bit late to post this. But may help someone else seeking for this later on.

Answer (score 2):

The Adobe documentation may be a good place to start: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/developing/mobile.html